# Display child div when hovering over parent div - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div that contains several divs that use the same class. It looks like this,

```
<div class="deck-content">
    <div class="deck-box">TEST
       <div class="deck-hidden">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deck-box">TEST
       <div class="deck-hidden">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="deck-box">TEST
       <div class="deck-hidden">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I hover over the div with the class name `deck-box` I want the div with the class name `deck-hidden` to become visible.

The problem is I do not know how many `deck-box` divs there will be. So I can not give them all a different ID name.

How can I hover over a `deck-box` and have its respective child `deck-hidden` be visible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
.deck-box:hover .deck-hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This works. I was unaware that it could be done with css! I actually had to add a `.` in front of `deck-hidden` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.deck-box').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('div').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).children('div').hide();
})
```

with [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/rp7uznh1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from 'Syahrul' is the right approach. But there is a mistake in representing class name, it will not work as you expected. The '.' is missing before the children class name.
The right answer is,

```
.deck-hidden {
   display: none;    
}
.deck-box:hover .deck-hidden {
   display: block;
}
```